# Single Variable calculus: trigonometric integral problem

Tags: calculus

Not a homework problem; I'm self-studying calculus from Serge Lang's book and am stuck on the following question.

Question: $\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2} dx$

My approach: Try to get rid of the square root sign.

Let $x = \sin t$, $dx = \cos t dt$, $t = \arcsin x$

$\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2} dx$

$= \int \sin^2t \sqrt{1-\sin^2t} \cos t dt$

$= \int \sin^2t \cos^2t dt$

$= \frac14 \int 4\sin^2t \cos^2t dt$

$= \frac14 \int (2\sin t \cos t)^2 dt$

$= \frac14 \int \sin^2(2t) dt$

$= \frac14 \int \frac{1-\cos4t}{2} dt$

$= \frac14 \int \frac12 - \frac{\cos4t}{2} dt$

$= \frac18 t - \frac18 \frac{\sin4t}{4}$

$= \frac18 \arcsin x - \frac{1}{32} \sin(4\arcsin x)$

How do I proceed on from here?

Comment: Where else do you need to go with this. Looks like you've solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add $C$.

In principle then you are finished, but further "simplification" may be useful.

Stop temporarily at your next to last line. Note that $\sin(4t)=2\sin 2t\cos 2t=4\sin t\cos t(1-2\sin^2 t)$. Now you can express all these things simply in terms of $x$.